# Post too large - GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

Estou realizando uma rotina de busca em todas as ocorrências que já foram concluidas, porém quando entro em alguma e seleciono o anexo meu **glassfish** retorna a seguinte mensagem

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Post too large
```

Alguém já passou por isso? dei uma pesquisada porém não achei nada para suprir minha dúvida.

**Obs.:** Estou utilizando o glassfish 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente aumentar o tamanho máximo do Post na tela de administração do GlassFish (Configurations -> Network Config -> Network Listeners -> http-listener).